# What design pattern does Java Executor framework implements?

Tags: java, design-patterns, abstract-factory, executors

My understanding is that it seems very similar to Abstract Factory.

Note:

The executor interface:

```
public interface Executor {
     public void execute();
}
```

And then there is an `Executors` class containing static factories for various `Executor` implementations.

Comment: One thing to note though a factory is mostly concerned with creation , while the Executor interface defines a method that is mostly concerned with execution of tasks.

Answer (score 6):

It's not [Abstract Factory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_factory_pattern). It is [Mediator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mediator_pattern) pattern coupled with [Command](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern) pattern.

Executor interface is command pattern. Implementing  `execute()` is obeying a **Command**.

According to GoF, Mediator pattern intent is:

> Allows loose coupling by encapsulating the way disparate sets of objects interact and communicate with each other. Allows for the actions of each object set to vary independently of one another.

**Mediator Pattern in JDK**

**java.util.Timer** class `scheduleXXX()` methods

**java.util.concurrent.Executor** class `execute()` method.

**java.lang.reflect.Method** class `invoke()` method

Have a look source [article](http://www.journaldev.com/1730/mediator-design-pattern-in-java-example-tutorial) for more details.

Comment: The Command pattern is exhibited by the Runnable which is executed, rather than the Executor itself.

Comment: Thanks for the link. But its more command pattern than mediator isn't it?
not really sure what behavior/component is following mediator design pattern, can you help explain?

Comment: Have a look at :https://github.com/mryndzionek/java_mediator to understand in better way